# Angular Material Autco-complete Clear

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

How do I append my own function when the clear button is clicked on the Angular Material Auto-complete.

URL: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/autocomplete

For example: I want to run myFunctyion() when the X button in the Auto-complete field is clicked.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The button comes from the following code's `ng-click`:

```
<button
                type="button"
                tabindex="-1"
                ng-if="$mdAutocompleteCtrl.scope.searchText && !$mdAutocompleteCtrl.isDisabled"
                ng-click="$mdAutocompleteCtrl.clear()">
              <md-icon md-svg-icon="md-close"></md-icon>
              <span class="md-visually-hidden">Clear</span>
            </button>
```

If you wrote a `button` element directive or a `mdVisuallyHidden` class directive with a high priority, you may be able to intercept the event and handle it yourself...

**OR** submit a pull request to add such an event to `https://github.com/angular/material/blob/master/src/components/autocomplete/js/autocompleteDirective.js`

Answer (score 0):

Agree with previous answer that "X" button will trigger `$mdAutocompleteCtrl.clear()`.

But my tips will bit different, beside write custom directive you can just put your function to `$mdAutocompleteCtrl.clear()` at `angular-material.js` library. Or make a public variable that can passing your function inside `$mdAutocompleteCtrl.clear()` function.

Actually `$mdAutocompleteCtrl.clear()` it self is only an alias for public method. The real function name at `angular-material.js` is `clearValue()`